# Separation of concerns para custom component?

Tags: javascript, extjs, model-view-controller, extjs4, extjs4.1

Using ExtJS to create a custom component that will be potentially shared between projects. Normally creating my views I would connect the events for each component / sub component to it's controller.

My first iteration was create a self-contained object (1 file containing all its code and events where this would normally be abstracted to a controller). This has advantages of being self contained in ONLY 1 file but sort of seems kind of wrong mixing presentation / logic into the same file.

Anyone know of an alternative way or is this accepted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with creating user controls. You could consider to make a self-containing component with multiple controls. What you could do to 'talk' with your app is firing custom events. Than you can use your own component and listen to your own events (if necessary).